# How to build a watcher in Elasticsearch for generating OTRS ticket?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, otrs, elasticsearch-watcher

I want to configure a elasticsearch webhook watcher , which will look for the keyword "error" in my indices and genarate an OTRS ticket, if found.

Right now I have following configuration :

```json
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {"interval": "1m"}
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {"match_all": "Error"}
        },
        "indices": ["*"]
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gte": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "actions" : {
  "create_otrs" : {
    "transform": {
      "script": """{"Ticket":{"Queue":"EngineeringTeam","Priority":"P3","CustomerUser":"root@localhost","Title":"RESTCreateTest","State":"new","Type":"Incident"},"Article":{"ContentType":"text/plain;charset=utf8","Subject":"RestCreateTest","Body":"Thisisonlyatest"}}"""
    },
    "webhook" : {
      "method" : "POST",
      "host" : "http://myotrs.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=<user>&Password=<pass>",
      "port": 9200,
      "body": "{{#toJson}}ctx.payload{{/toJson}}",
      "auth" : {
        "basic" : {
          "username" : "elastic", 
          "password" : "<elasticsearch pass>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

This gives me `Error saving watch : compile error` and watcher will not simulate. There is no syntax error in the json by the way. What is wrong in the configuration? A curl operation successfully generates the OTRS ticket but I am getting a hard time configuring it with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

Your transform script is wrong.
As per the documentation:

> The executed script may either return a valid model that is the equivalent of a Java™ Map or a JSON object (you will need to consult the documentation of the specific scripting language to find out what this construct is).

## Solution

You can do something as simple as, converting your json into a string

```json
{
  "Ticket": {
    "Queue": "EngineeringTeam",
    "Priority": "P3",
    "CustomerUser": "root@localhost",
    "Title": "RESTCreateTest",
    "State": "new",
    "Type": "Incident"
  },
  "Article": {
    "ContentType": "text/plain;charset=utf8",
    "Subject": "RestCreateTest",
    "Body": "Thisisonlyatest"
  }
}
```

Becomes:

```
"{\"Ticket\":{\"Queue\":\"EngineeringTeam\",\"Priority\":\"P3\",\"CustomerUser\":\"root@localhost\",\"Title\":\"RESTCreateTest\",\"State\":\"new\",\"Type\":\"Incident\"},\"Article\":{\"ContentType\":\"text/plain;charset=utf8\",\"Subject\":\"RestCreateTest\",\"Body\":\"Thisisonlyatest\"}}"
```

And use the `Json.load` function to convert the string into a proper object.

Your watch will look like:

```json
{
  "watch" : {
    "trigger": {
      "schedule": {"interval": "1m"}
    },
    "input": {
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "body": {
            "size": 0,
            "query": {"match_all": "Error"}
          },
          "indices": ["*"]
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "compare": {
        "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
          "gte": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "actions" : {
      "create_otrs" : {
        "transform": {
          "script": """return Json.load("{\"Ticket\":{\"Queue\":\"EngineeringTeam\",\"Priority\":\"P3\",\"CustomerUser\":\"root@localhost\",\"Title\":\"RESTCreateTest\",\"State\":\"new\",\"Type\":\"Incident\"},\"Article\":{\"ContentType\":\"text/plain;charset=utf8\",\"Subject\":\"RestCreateTest\",\"Body\":\"Thisisonlyatest\"}}");"""
        },
        "webhook" : {
          "method" : "POST",
          "host" : "http://myotrs.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=<user>&Password=<pass>",
          "port": 9200,
          "body": "{{#toJson}}ctx.payload{{/toJson}}",
          "auth" : {
            "basic" : {
              "username" : "elastic", 
              "password" : "<elasticsearch pass>"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then another error you have in your watch is the query

```json
{
  "search": {
    "request": {
      "body": {
        "size": 0,
        "query": {"match_all": "Error"}
      },
      "indices": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

`match_all` should take an object such as `{}` so `"Error"` is not going to work.

So in the end the watcher looks like:

```json
{
  "watch" : {
    "trigger": {
      "schedule": {"interval": "1m"}
    },
    "input": {
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "body": {
            "size": 0,
            "query": {"match_all": {}}
          },
          "indices": ["*"]
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "compare": {
        "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
          "gte": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "actions" : {
      "create_otrs" : {
        "transform": {
          "script": """return Json.load("{\"Ticket\":{\"Queue\":\"EngineeringTeam\",\"Priority\":\"P3\",\"CustomerUser\":\"root@localhost\",\"Title\":\"RESTCreateTest\",\"State\":\"new\",\"Type\":\"Incident\"},\"Article\":{\"ContentType\":\"text/plain;charset=utf8\",\"Subject\":\"RestCreateTest\",\"Body\":\"Thisisonlyatest\"}}");"""
        },
        "webhook" : {
          "method" : "POST",
          "host" : "http://myotrs.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=<user>&Password=<pass>",
          "port": 9200,
          "body": "{{#toJson}}ctx.payload{{/toJson}}",
          "auth" : {
            "basic" : {
              "username" : "elastic", 
              "password" : "<elasticsearch pass>"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I made the changes, also I tried `"query": {"match_all": {}}` and alternately `"query": { "match" : { "message" : "error" } }` , but it still shows compile error..

Comment: I ran it in console and it has problems with json.load function .  Default ` lang:painless`

Comment: which version are you running because it is working on my side, in `8.6`

Comment: I am using version `8.6`. `json.load` did not work though. However I used your construct and `painless` lang to get the watcher working

Comment: Have you noticed it is `Json` not `json` ?

Comment: Heyy, its working ! I made certain error at the first time I guess. However for ticket creation we have give params field too and its working fine. Now I learnt two methods of building scripts. Thanx